# Ubuntu Raring - OpenLayers Plugin 1.8 or 1.9 Master

Tags: python, openlayers-2, ubuntu, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Relative newbie to Ubuntu and QGIS.  Many questions are posted relating to the OpenLayers plugin.  It works fine in windows but I cannot get it to work or even appear in either 1.8 or 1.9. The "`fetch python plugins`" option is missing from the menu.  I've tried the temporary fix for 1.9, also no go.

I've used Synaptic packet manager, the wiki and sources.list and every other tip.  It does not work.  I can install, uninstall, purge, clear the source.list, remove entries from Synaptic, re-install from software centre, etc etc but nothing works.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on Ubuntu Raring, but using a version built from source (master).